# Python documentation for os.removexattr -- what does the '*' (star) argument mean?

Tags: python, operating-system, file-attributes

My first question, please be gentle. I searched but could not find an answer here or elsewhere.

Note that this question does not apply to unpacking of arguments like *args.

In the python 3.3 documentation for [os.removexattr](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.html?highlight=os#os.removexattr) the following is stated:

```
os.removexattr(path, attribute, *, follow_symlinks=True)

    Removes the extended filesystem attribute attribute from path.
    attribute should be bytes or str. If it is a string, it is encoded
    with the filesystem encoding.

    This function can support specifying a file descriptor and not
    following symlinks.
```

Note that the third argument is a star: *

I assumed that this means "specify one attribute or several attributes separated by comma",
but when trying to do that, I get an exception:

```
import os
os.removexattr('M7-AAE-01.jpg', 'user.camera_brand', 'user.camera_model')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    TypeError: Function takes at most 2 positional arguments (3 given)
```

I also tried to supply a list of arguments, but that did not work either.

What exactly does the star argument mean in this case?
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The single asterisk `*` just means that it is forcing you to use named arguments. In this case if you want to pass a value for `follow_symlinks`, you have to pass the argument name.

The idea is you don't having to read function calls like `foo(True, False, False)` and not know what those values are doing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I have looked at a few more Python documentation examples and realized that the * argument is always used before named arguments, so this is definitely the right answer. I have to say though, it is rather confusing, as it appears that the star would be another argument of some "magic" kind. Instead one should interpret it as "the * argument indicates that any arguments hereafter are named arguments". Something like that...

Comment: @user3122335: well, it seems your observation is not universal; for example `os.utime(path, times=None, *, [ns, ]dir_fd=None, follow_symlinks=True)`. Or is `ns` a keyword argument here as well?

Comment: From the Python reference (https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions): Parameters after “*” or “*identifier” are keyword-only parameters and may only be passed used keyword arguments.